# How do I make hopper to push only one item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

first of all I know there are some topics on this issue already, but none of them actually answers my question.

Im building a simple trade machine. Lets say you throw 1 iron ingot into the hopper, youll get 1 gold ingot for example from dropper.

Problem is, I followed countless of tutorials for my version Java 1.12.2 and guys seem to get it working. My game is acting diferently for no reason.

I know I need to lock hopper to take only desired currency, in my case, iron ingot. So i need to lock hopper with one stackable item and 4 non-stackable items.

(For example I have from up to down Hopper > hopper > Chest. Now i locked second hopper with 63 iron ingots and 4 swords. When i throw one ingot to the top hopper, it goes through, push one item out of dropper and when i check the locked hopper, its not on 63, its on 61, so it pushed 3 items instead of that one).

So yeah, the problem is, my dropper push 3 items into the chest so person needs to throw 3 ingots to get one in exchange.

Is there ANY way to make it 1 for 1? I dont understand why is my redstone/hopper machines acting differently if Im following tutorials step by step for my version of Minecraft.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Have you built the [standard item sorter](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Hopper#Item_sorter)? If yes and it doesn't work, do you use mods?

Comment: Besides your item filter sounding really weird (4 *non-stackable* items??), check if the server you play on doesn't have a plugin that makes a hopper operate in increment of 3. Point a hopper into a chest, fill with junk, observe the chest. If the contents increase by 1 (every 0.4s), it's vanilla behavior. If they increase in other increments, it's a server plugin.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for answers. I tried to do that machine in my own creative and its working as it should be (how could I not try that earlier tho). Hopper on server is taking 3 items, yes, so its probably their plugin.